# How to retrieve data from a CSV file w/o opening it

Tags: excel, csv

Is there any way to retrieve data from a csv file into an excel sheet without opening the CSV file? I am working on windows PC. Excel sheet and CSV file are in one folder. I also have a program running that is continuously updating the data in CSV file. If i open CSV file directly then program will stop running. So I need an alternative solution to read the data from CSV file without opening it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Clearly you cannot work with file without working with file. You can e.g. make a copy of file and open it instead. Without clarification of what languages and tech is available it isn't seems to be possible to answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957451/how-can-i-open-an-excel-file-read-write-for-some-users-and-readonly-for-others/22958386#22958386 - you can open the csv file as readonly via VBA

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to read from the `CAV` file *without locking it* so your other process can continue to write to it.

This can be achieved with the `FileSystemObject`

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim txt As TextStream
    Dim s As String
    On Error GoTo EH

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Your\Path\YourFile.csv", ForReading)
```

Opening the file `ForReading` doesn't lock it, your other process can continue to write to it.  You can now read from it with

```
    Do While Not txt.AtEndOfStream
        s = txt.ReadLine
        Debug.Print s
    Loop
```

This will read through to the current end of file.  If more data is added to the file while your code is still doing something else, you can continue to use `txt.ReadLine` to get more data.

To start reading from the start again, execute

```
    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Your\Path\YourFile.csv", ForReading)
```

again.

Clean up with

```
EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    txt.Close
    Set txt = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but its giving me a compiler error. "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: You need to set a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (from then Tools / Refrences menu)

Comment: Ok, reference is set to Microsoft Scripting Runtime but i still can't get it working :(